# IONIC 3 [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

i start for ionic 3, but i try to run command 'ionic cordova run android', i was try any way for solve this problem but i cannot found answer from this problem, i got error like this :

```
this result error
[13:29:45]  preprocess started ...
[13:29:45]  deeplinks started ...
[13:29:45]  deeplinks finished in 44 ms
[13:29:45]  preprocess finished in 52 ms
[13:29:45]  webpack started ...
[13:29:45]  copy finished in 14.20 s
[13:30:30]  webpack finished in 45.55 s
[13:30:30]  sass started ...
[13:30:36]  sass finished in 5.48 s
[13:30:36]  postprocess started ...
[13:30:36]  postprocess finished in 22 ms
[13:30:36]  lint started ...
[13:30:36]  build dev finished in 64.67 s
[13:30:36]  watch ready in 65.09 s
[13:30:36]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

> cordova run android
[13:30:46]  lint finished in 10.69 s
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

this my ionic info:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI             : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI               : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 7
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ionic cordova run android -> Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

Comment: try running `cordova run android` command..

Comment: i was try that command, but result not change, result still error

Comment: what does `cordova requirements` give?

Comment: Cordova requirements I have filled it all, but still appear the same error

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem ,
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

Use following command in CLI:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
npm cache clear
ionic cordova run android
```

also update or create new AVD in android studio.